# How to get Bar Chart in table format in Matplotlib or other library?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I am fairly new to matplotlib or the whole idea of visualisation using python. I have an assignment in which we are asked to provide insights in this way. I have tried searching over the google but I think I am searching something wrong.
[image: BarChart in Table]

I have tried plotting the graph horizontally with table but I am still able to create something which similar to the image. Is it a different library?